shell exit function for set -e
I have a script.command file with a shell script inside, so that I can double click it to execute in a new terminal window. When it finishes the script it automatically closes regardless of the exit code. Back in the days I used to put ifs after every troublesome command like this:
iCanCouseError
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    read -p "Press enter to close"
    exit 1
fi

This was keeping the terminal open until I press a button, so that I could read the logs and determine what caused an exception.
But now I switched to a much more convenient method: set -e at the beginning of the file. It automatically exits the script with an error code if any command fails. But now I can't read logs before the terminal closes. I wonder if there is some way to set an exit function in addition to set -e that will always execute right before script exits, so that I could put read command there to stop terminal from closing in case of non-zero exit code.

Don't use set -e. Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 to learn why.

Configure your terminal emulator to not close the window immediately after the command it executes completes.

@chepner I think the issue is the OP only wants the window to remain open if there was an error (I have the same situation with a tool of mine - I don't want to have to manually close the window in the 99% of cases where it succeeded).

If you're using bash, please add the [tag:bash] tag to your question. If not, add the appropriate tag for whichever shell you're using (ksh? zsh?).

Package up your commands in a separate "iCanCauseError" executable script file that starts with a shebang.
Then iCanCauseError || read -p "Press enter" suffices.
A zero exit value will be interpreted as True,
satifying the short-circuiting OR operator,
so it doesn't have to evaluate that second disjunct.
Notice that we have a separate Bash child running the commands,
rather than say a (subshell) or function within current shell.

Also, when setting -e, you might as well set this:
set -e -o pipeline

Imagine you do grep x y | sort | awk ... | wc -l,
and the awk script bombs out with non-zero exit status.
The effect of setting the pipeline option is to make that fatal,
similar to how set -e makes non-zero status fatal for single command.
It's just less surprising.
And while you're at it, the unrelated set -u may be of interest.
This will do variable interpolation: echo ${HOME}/.
But imagine there's a typographic error, so we
accidentally get just a / slash output: echo  ${HOMS}/.
The "unset variable" -u setting will make that typo a fatal error.

This doesn't work because set -e won't apply in the function anymore. The function will run cmd2 even if cmd1 fails.

Consider not using set -e as it's a mess (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and also consider setting a trap to do something different for success vs other exit statuses instead of putting code below your "real" code, something like:
sig_handler() {
    exit_status=$?
    echo "Doing signal-specific stuff"
    exit "$exit_status"
}

trap sig_handler INT HUP TERM QUIT

iCanCouseError

Google for better alternative trap functions/usage, there are plenty of suggestions out there for you to choose from dependent on what you want to do.
